# Write to Nested Dictionary (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, dictionary, collections

I have declared a dictionary in Swift as so: `var dict = [String: [String: [String]]]()`.

What I am trying to do now is to write to the nested dictionary. I have used both codes below, however, none of them work as the initial key does not exist:

```
dict["Test"]?["One"] = ["Failed"]
dict["Test"]!["One"] = ["Failed"]
```

What I am trying to do is to create a key for `["One"]`, much like how you can create a key for a normal dictionary using `dict[key]`.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: yes i did! thank you, but I don't know why I can't accept your answer. I don't see the green checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate every inner dictionary.

```
var dict = [String : [String : [String]]]()

dict["Test"] = [String : [String]]()

dict["Test"]?["One"] = ["Worked"]

print(dict)
```

Make sure to avoid force unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

`dict` is empty. There is no value for the `"Test"` key.

One option is to provide a default:

```
dict["Test", default: [:]]["One"] = ["A", "B"]
```

You can take this one step further:

```
dict["Test2", default: [:]]["Two", default: []].append("Hello")
```

That last line will work for any combination of the keys `"Test2"` and `"Two"` existing or not before that is used.